# Need help proving a function is absolutely integrable.

Tags: analysis

Prove that $f(x)=\frac{sinx}{x^2}$ is absolutely integrable on $[\pi,\infty)$.

Comment: It's bounded by $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left \vert \frac{\sin x}{x^2} \right \vert \leq \frac {1}{x^2}$ and $\frac {1}{x^2}$ is integrable over that domain.